# Load iframe html tag in django template to show maps

Tags: python, django, iframe

I have a django application where I am showing details of hospitals located in different location.
I am able to render all the details but unable to render the source of iframe location to the template.

Below is my field to get source of iframe location.

**models.py**

```
class mydetails(models.Model):
    Name=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    City=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    Location=models.TextField(max_length=5000,blank=True) #getting source of iframe
```

And I am rendering the the value of location as below in my html.
**views.py**

```
class my_detailpage(generic.DetailView):
    model = mydetails
    template_name = 'hospital_app/detail.html'
```

**detail.html**

```
<iframe class="g-maps" src="{{ mydetails.Location}}" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>
```

the content inside the iframe source looks some thing like `https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3806.9740157153647!2d78.46347561744385!3d17.413034599999996!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3bcb975afb4afadd%3A0xf89ea8407df6c84!2sPrasads%20Multiplex!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1595574993123!5m2!1sen!2sin`

I tried taking the Location value as URLField as well in my models but was of no help.
When I inspected my template, found that my source details were empty even after loading the tag.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the relevant details from your `views.py`?

Comment: @MattRowbum Added the details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that when using a [`DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview), your model instance is accessed as `object` in the template:

```html
<iframe src="{{ object.Location }}"></iframe>
```

You can change this by providing a `context_object_name` as [noted here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#making-friendly-template-contexts) in the docs.